# How to use sound and images in a Java applet?

Tags: java, deployment, jar, applet

Question 1: How should I structure my project so the sound and images files can be loaded most easily? Right now, I have the folder:

```
C:\java\pacman
```

with the sub-directory

```
C:\java\pacman\src
```

containing all the code, and

```
C:\java\pacman\assets
```

containing the images and .wav files. Is this the best structure or should I put the assets somewhere else?

Question 2:

What's the best way to refer to the images/sounds without using the full path e.g `C:\java\pacman\assets\something.png` to them? If I use the `getCodeBase()` function it seems to refer to the `C:\java\pacman\bin` instead of `C:\java\pacman\`.

I want to use such a function/class which would work automatically when i compile the applet in a jar as well as right now when I test the applet through eclipse.

Question 3: How should I load the images/sounds? This is what I'm using now:

1) For general images:

```
import java.awt.Image;

public Image getImg(String file)
{
          //imgDir in this case is a hardcoded string containing
          //"C:\\java\\pacman\\assets\\"
    file=imgDir + file;
    return new ImageIcon(file).getImage();
}
```

The images returned from this function are used in the `drawImage` method of the `Graphics` class in the `paint` method of the applet.

2) For a buffered image, which is used to get subImages and load sprites from a sprite sheet:

```
public BufferedImage getSheet() throws IOException
{
    return ImageIO.read(new File(img.getPath("pacman-sprites.png")));

}
```

Later:

```
public void loadSprites()
{
    BufferedImage sheet;
    try
    {
        sheet=getSheet();

        redGhost.setNormalImg(sheet.getSubimage(0, 60, 20, 20));
        redGhost.setUpImg(sheet.getSubimage(0, 60, 20, 20));
        redGhost.setDownImg(sheet.getSubimage(30, 60, 20, 20));
        redGhost.setLeftImg(sheet.getSubimage(30, 60, 20, 20));
        redGhost.setRightImg(sheet.getSubimage(60, 60, 20, 20));    
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Couldnt open file!");
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }   
}
```

3) For sound files:

```
import sun.audio.*;
import java.io.*;
public synchronized void play() {
    try {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);
            AudioStream as = new AudioStream(in);
            AudioPlayer.player.start(as); 

    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place them on your classpath (place them with your .class files) and load them using the [ClassLoader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html).

Java:

```
package mypackage;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.net.URL url = MyClass.class.getResource("/mypackage/image.gif");
        System.out.println(url);
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
C:\resource>dir /b /s
C:\resource\bin
C:\resource\src
C:\resource\bin\mypackage
C:\resource\bin\mypackage\image.gif
C:\resource\bin\mypackage\MyClass.class
C:\resource\src\mypackage
C:\resource\src\mypackage\MyClass.java

C:\resource>java -cp bin mypackage.MyClass
file:/C:/resource/bin/mypackage/image.gif
```

Comment: Doesn't work :( always returns null even when I put the image in the class path

Comment: System.out.println("It is " + file + " , "  + this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(file));
 gives: "It ispacman-intro.png , null" , and on the next line i get an IllegalArgumentException when I try to use the null file

Comment: Put the .png where you have your java file and do: URL url = this.getClass().getResource("player.png");
        System.out.println(url);